# Logic for "slight right turn" given three points

Tags: geometry, mapping, directions, cross-product

Given three co-planar (2D) points (X1, Y1), (X2, Y2), and (X3, Y3), which represent (respectively ...) "1=where I was, 2=where I am, and 3=where I am going," I need a simple algorithm that will tell me, e.g.

- Veer to the right
- Make a slight left turn
- Turn to the left

In other words, (a) is the turn to the left or to the right; and (b) how sharp is the turn (letting me be arbitrary about this).

For the first part, I've already learned about how to use (see wikipedia: Graham Scan, and question #26315401 here) cross-product to determine whether the turn is to the left or to the right, based on whether the path is counterclockwise.

And, I'm sure that ATAN2() will be at the core of determining how sharp the turn is.

But I can't .. quite .. wrap my head around the proper math which will work in *all* orientations.  (Especially when the angle crosses the zero-line.  (A bearing of 350 degrees to 10 degrees is a gap of 20 degrees, not 340, *etc*.)

Okay, I'm *tired.* [... of bangin' my head against the wall this mornin'.]  "Every time I think I've got it, I'm not sure."  So, okay, it's time to ask ...  :-)

Comment: (Author's Note):  this is a mapping-app situation.  The first two points establish the direction of travel; the third is where the traveler is now turning-to.  All three points are known to be "sensible."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you calculate direction change angles with Atan2, don't bother about absolute angles. You have not to calculate two bearings and subtract them -  Atan2 can give you **relative angle** between the first and the second vectors in range `-Pi..Pi (-180..180)` (range might depend on programming language).

```
x12 = x2-x1
y12 = y2-y1
x23 = x3-x2
y23 = y3-y2
DirChange = Atan2(x12*y23-x23*y12, x12*x23+y12*y23)
```

Some explanations: we can calculate sine of vector-vector angle through cross product and vector norms (`|A| = Sqrt(A.x*A.x + A.y*A.y)`):

```
Sin(A_B) = (A x B) / (|A|*|B|)
```

and cosine of vector-vector angle through dot (scalar) product and vector norms:

```
Cos(A_B) = (A * B) / (|A|*|B|)
```

Imagine that Atan2 calculates angle with sine and cosine of this angle, excluding common denominator (product of norms)

```
A_B = Atan2(Sin(A_B), Cos(A_B))
```

Example in Delphi:

```
var
  P1, P2, P3: TPoint;
  x12, y12, x23, y23: Integer;
  DirChange: Double;
begin
  P1 := Point(0, 0);
  P2 := Point(1, 0);
  P3 := Point(2, 1);
  x12 := P2.X - P1.X;
  y12 := P2.Y - P1.Y;
  x23 := P3.X - P2.X;
  y23 := P3.Y - P2.Y;
  DirChange := Math.ArcTan2(x12 * y23 - x23 * y12, x12 * x23 + y12* y23);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%f radians   %f degrees',
    [DirChange, RadToDeg(DirChange)]));
```

Output:
`0.79 radians   45.00 degrees` (left turn)

for your example data set (1,1), (3,2), and (6,3)

`-0.14 radians   -8.13 degrees` (right turn)

Comment: Diffs between programming-languages is no problem.  :-)  Now, it looks to me like you're calculating the ATAN2 of two "cross-products" here.  I'm trying hard to visualize the math here (given that I know what ATAN2 is, etc).  Could you (or someone) elaborate a bit?  Why this will give me the right-answer even if one vector is "350º" and the other  is "10º?"  What's the rationale for using cross-products to compute the two inputs to ATAN2?  (I'm not doubting you, but "the little light-bulb" hasn't clicked-on quite yet.)  :-X

Comment: The second term is scalar product. Look at additions.

Comment: Thank you.  Now, will you for-the-record clarify your use of the various punctuation marks in your edited response, "for the benefit of the peanut gallery" as well as for me.  Lowercase-"x" I guess means cross-product, vertical-bar can't (I guess) mean "absolute value." ... And then, when I look at your "Sin()" and "Cos()" equations, and try to compare these with the expressions for "DirChange =", I don't see the division "/" operator used even once.  Also:  I know might be 'bout time to refer-out to an external web-page (of your choice) that gently-explains these magicks...  M-A-N-Y thanks!

Comment: I'm not getting the expected result. (See "answer #2" response ... which oddly enough appears "above.")

Comment: Yes, 'x' is for cross-product, '*' is for scalar product (dot product), vertical-bars denote norm - length of the vector (formula added). Division is not needed with Atan2 function.

Comment: ... THANKS(!) for bearing with me.  :-)  Quite a difference between the "Sin()" and "Cos()" formulas, which involve Sqrt(), and the original "DirChange" formula which didn't.

Comment: I've added full example

Comment: Note that you don't need sin, cos, and sqrt to calculate bearing change.

Comment: My spreadsheet replicated your first number (45 degrees), but for the second it gives a result of 1.769 radians = 101.3 degrees.  However, it is also obvious that "it must be the spreadsheet."  I thank you MOST kindly for your excellent, and patient(!), answer.  "Thanks.  I needed that."  :-D

Comment: BINGO!!  On this spreadsheet, the order of parameters is (X,Y).  On Delphi (and in most other programming languages), it's (Y,X).  When I flip-flopped the order of the parameters, I replicated your promised result.  (I also then confirmed it using Perl.)  For the first answer, the flip-flop didn't matter.  Again, thank you for the thoroughness and persistence of your response.  This is EXACTLY what I needed.

Comment: In Javascript I also got -11.31 degrees (right turn). The points from (1,3) through (3,2) to (6,1) is exactly the same amount of angle to easilly see it compared to (1,1)-(3,2)-(6,3) when I wrote it down as a graph in a collegie block. It is a left turn so it should be +11.31 degrees, but now Math.atan2 (if not this answer) has some odds. I get 169 degrees from the formula. Have used *180/Math.PI to get from RadToDeg. Have also tried to reverse Y-axis because engineers felt it easiest to have origo in upper left corner. I get 169 instead, that is 180 - 11. It should be a slight turn of 11!

Comment: @Pauli Sudarshan Terho You have discovered old lasting mistake - wrong expression for dot product ;) Corrections done.

Comment: Credible! It now works in all directions. One `Math.arsctan2` instead of two! I can confirm in my SVG line drawing as it outputs correct values and signs for each turn. Now I can detect figures :D Yee

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED - THE FOLLOWING IS WRONG.** *My ORIGINAL response was as follows ...*

I'm not coming up with the expected answers when I try to use your response.

Let's say the points are:  (1,1), (3,2), and (6,3).  A gentle right turn.

Using a spreadsheet, I come up with:  X12=2, X23=3, Y12=1, Y23=3, and the ATAN2 result (in degrees) is 101.3.  A very sharp turn of more than 90 degrees.  The spreadsheet formula (listing X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3,X12,X23,Y12,Y23 and answer) on row 2, is:

```
=DEGREES(ATAN2(G2*J2-H2*I2; G2*I2+H2*J2))
```

(The spreadsheet, OpenOffice, lists "X" as the first parameter to ATAN2.)

Are you certain that the typo is on my end?

**AND, AS A MATTER OF FACT (SO TO SPEAK), "YES, IT WAS!"**

*(Heh, I actually had said it myself. It just didn't occur to me to, like, duh, swap them already.)*

My spreadsheet's version of the ATAN2 function specifies the *X* parameter first.  Most programming languages *(Delphi, Perl, PHP ...)* specify *Y* first, and that's how the (correct!) answer was given.

When I edited the formula, reversing the parameters to meet the spreadsheet's definition, the problem went away, and I was able to reproduce the values from the *(edited)* reply.  Here's the corrected formula, with the parameters reversed:

```
=DEGREES(ATAN2(G2*I2+H2*J2; G2*J2-H2*I2))
               ^^== X ==^^  ^^== Y ==^^
```

Again, this change in formula was needed because *this spreadsheet's* implementation of ATAN2 is backwards from that of most programming language implementations.  The answer that was originally given, which lists Y first, *is correct* for most programming languages.

Comment: Usual parameter order is Atan2(Y, X), but it depends on language amd math library. If your spreadsheet script language has revert order, exchange cross and scalar product terms

Comment: Exactly so.  Exactly so.  Your answer (as noted) followed the customary programming-language practice (Y,X).  My spreadsheet does the opposite, and ... well ... eventually the little light-bulb *did* come on in my brain.

Comment: Y23 = P3.Y - P2.Y => 3 - 2 = 1. How you calculated it to be 3?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I seem to *still* be having a bit of a problem . . .

If the points are very far away from each other in nearly a straight line, I am coming up with "large angles."  Example:

P1: (0.60644,0.30087) .. 
P2: (0.46093,0.30378) .. 
P3: (0.19335,0.30087)

*The X-coordinate increases but the Y-coordinate remains almost the same.*

x12=-0.145507 .. y12=-0.00290698

x23=-0.267578125 .. y23=0.002906976

*(I inverted the Y differences because the coordinates are in quadrant-IV, where Y increases downward.)*

x=-0.000354855 .. y=-0.00120083

ans= -106.462  *(degrees)*

Since the points are very nearly co-linear, I expected the answer to  be very small.  As you can see, it's more than 106 degrees.

Comment: On the assumption that the *sign* of the prior result is trustworthy if not its *value*, I added logic to compute the angle between the two vectors like this: _('leftright' is the previous calculation)_ `var result = Math.abs(degrees( Math.atan2(y12, x12) - Math.atan2( y23, x23 ) ));
  if (result > 180.0) result = 360.0 - result;
  if (leftright < 0) result = (-result);` Is that necessary? I doubt it. (And I would like to know!) "But: it seems to work."  And sometimes, that's what you need.  Once again, many thanks.